# Trying to translate text into pictures

Tags: javascript, image, search, text, browser-extension

I try to run a browser extension, which translates the text on a page into pictures, searched on google.

I only use javascript and was able to search for the inner text in the html page, but I struggle with the next step. How can I use the known text on the page to search for it on google/images and after searching, how can I use the pictures on the webpage? [I want the page to be like this, but with the searched pictures, should be easy with a grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMnHs.jpg)

If you know a complete idea, how to do everything, just let me know. If you know some kind of add-ons or sth to make it easier or better, just let me know. I try to adopt your ideas in this project!

Thank you for helping me.